# How to enter hexadecimal values from the extended ASCII table

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, input, ascii

I am running Ubuntu 14.10, and I would like to enter characters from the console using hexadecimal code. To do this, I am using the combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>+Hexcode. On my computer this works fine until Ascii character 127, but entering a value above will result in a character different from the extended Ascii table. For example, <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>+FF results in a y with two dots above. This is not the correct value from the ASCII table. I guess I need to configure my character set, but I don`t know how. I only found foreign sets like hyroglyphs. How can I ender ASCII characters from the extended Ascii set?

Best regards,

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

According to this [table in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII#/media/File:Table_ascii_extended.png) the character corresponding to ASCII 255 or 0xff *is* 'ÿ'. However I produced this character with Ctrl-Shift-u followed by 'ff', not Alt-Shift-u and 'ff'. (After entering Ctrl-Shift-u, an underligned u appears, then continue typing the hex code and terminate with `Enter` to get the coded character.)

Comment: That is interesting, I thought this was the extended ASCII table : http://asciiset.com . Are there different sets? Can I somehow change the table?

Comment: This is interesting, I thought this was the ASCII table http://asciiset.com . Are there different ASCII tables?

Comment: The page you linked says itself that there are different versions for the extended table. I suppose it's a matter of encoding, see `locale`.